# How to authenticate PhpStorm HTTP Client request to Magento 2 REST API?

Tags: intellij-idea, magento, oauth, phpstorm, magento2

I'm trying to emulate request for updating product information from third-party system to Magento 2 REST API using PhpStorm HTTP Client. Authentication type is [Integration (oAuth)](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/get-started/authentication/#integration-oauth). Are there any solutions for composing authenticated request?

I could not find any ready to use method out of the box.

Comment: Not specific to your issue (Magento 2 REST API), but rather a general comment for OAuth support in HTTP Client. [IDEA-239311 for OAuth](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-239311) and [IDEA-314199 for OAuth2](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-314199) were marked as "Fixed" recently and will be available in the **next major 2023.3 version**. You can try the [EAP build](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/nextversion/) and see if it works for you (if not current #2 then the next #4).

Comment: Check the comments in the first ticket nevertheless for *possible* workarounds in the current 2023.2 version (i.e. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-239311#focus=Comments-27-7893459.0-0 )